# Java: equivalent to C++ const method

Tags: java, c++, constants

In C++, one can define a const **method**:

```
class MyClass {
    void myMethod() const {
        .. code ..
    };
};
```

The `const` here means that this method has only read permissions to `this`. I.e., it cannot make any change to the object it works on. It can only make read operations on it.

Is there an equivalent in Java for **const method**?

Comment: There is no direct equivalent for this in java.

Comment: @ifLoop        I was gonna blab out 'final' but realised that it is for class inheritence stuff....:P...so deleted my comment

Comment: There's no such thing in Java. Just make sure you don't modify "this". A plain "getter" in Java will do the job..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an answer from my comment: There is no equivalent for this in java.

A member function has always write access to the fields of it's class. If you want to change that behavior, you have to move the function outside the class and hand over a copy to it.